# Getting a "nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments'' error. How should I proceed with fixing it?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I've started working on a project and have a bug that I'm trying to figure what to do with.

I'm getting a "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'some_DB_Process'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored" error when running the code below.

The process that I'm calling from the back end is an internal process of the customer's database for which we only have the signature.

This is part of the code that I'm running during the request:

```py
cur = connection.cursor()
ptID = check_user_auth()
request_data = json.loads(request.data)
prId = request_data.get('pr_Id')

a = '150'
b = cur.var(int)
c = cur.var(str)
d = cur.var(str)
reqID = crete_request(ptID, prId)
request_data['request_id'] = reqID.getvalue()


r_amf = None
r_amk = None
if prId == '12345':
    try:
        r_amf = next(item[54323] for item in request_data['data'] if item.get(54323))
        r_amk = next(item[54324] for item in request_data['data'] if item.get(54324))
    except:
        pass


'''More code that eventually leads to:'''
    

    try:
        cur.callproc('some_DB_Process', [reqID.getvalue(), a, b, c, d, r_amf, r_amk])
        connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        connection.rollback()
        g.pool.release(connection)
        return json.dumps({'status': '0', 'msg': 'DB Process Error: {}'.format(e),'error_data':'reqID:{}, a: {}, b: {},c: {}, d: {},r_amf: {}, r_amk: {}'.format(reqID.getvalue(),a,b,c,d, r_amf,r_amk)})
```

Procedure Signature:

```sql
PROCEDURE some_DB_Process(reqID IN NUMBER,
                         a IN VARCHAR2,
                         b   IN OUT NUMBER,
                         c  IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                         d IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                         r_b_log in varchar2 default null,
                         r_r_num in varchar2 default null,
                         r_amk in varchar2 default null,
                         r_amf in varchar2 default null);
```

When running the code, I'm getting an error message during the callproc part with the above error and the following data :

```
 "error_data": 
 reqID:1234554321, 
 a: 150, 
 b: <cx_Oracle.Var of type DB_TYPE_NUMBER with value None>,
 c: <cx_Oracle.Var of type DB_TYPE_VARCHAR with value None>, 
 d: <cx_Oracle.Var of type DB_TYPE_VARCHAR with value None>,
 r_amf: None, 
 r_amk: None
```

I'm unsure why this error happens.
Is it because some of the values are Null/None or is it because the procedure is not called correctly?
I haven't touched the callproc call, or the arguments in it and I'm told that it was tested successfully in the past, but it baffles me that the arguments would work like they are. I would expect to at least have a requirement to pass them using key-value pairs so that you know which argument is which or at least pass them in the correct order (for example the r_amf and r_amk are in reverse order and the r_b_log and r_b_num don't appear at all in the process call - being told that it used to work I assumed that default values applied but the order still baffles me a little bit.)

My current line of thinking is that we perhaps need a way to get values for the b,c and d variables for which we'll have to contact the customer for information on where these pieces of info are located, as that would solve the None value, but would that solve the issue or would I have to also change how the process is called?
If I just change the process call to include the 2 missing variables and fix the order will the None value still be a problem?

Thanks a lot,
Bill

Comment: It doesn't matter if some of them have default values, though?

Comment: oh yes, didn't notice them, but do you observe the order of `r_amf` and `r_amk` ? They're stated at 6th and 7th places while should be 8th and 9th.

Comment: Do you think that the None values create the error?

Comment: Yes, I did observe the order! I'll change that - it's just that I was told that this was working correctly before and didn't wanna change something that seemed off on the premises that it worked.

Comment: retry to call with adding null parameters for `r_b_log` and `r_r_num`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Do you think that the problem might be that those 3 variables which are required, take a null value?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a sequence of parameters to callproc(), those parameters will be passed to the procedure in the same order they are provided. So in your example above the values in the variables r_amf and r_amk will actually be passed as parameters r_b_log and r_r_num in the PL/SQL procedure!

Null values (None) are perfectly acceptable inputs to any type.

A quick scan of the data supplied and the procedure definition provided doesn't indicate any obvious issues. I would suggest creating a dummy version of your procedure that has the same signature but doesn't do anything useful and create a standalone script that calls this stored procedure with hard-coded data (such as what you provided above). If that standalone script fails, update your question accordingly and I'll attempt to help further.

Comment: Thank you! 
I'll try to do that on Tuesday when I'll be back to work and update the question as necessary!